# direct and indirect reports of manager in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named reports with the columns employee id(eid) and parenteid(peid) and role. And there are 4 roles (director, organizer, volunteer, contact).

I am looking to find the count of direct and indirect reports for the different directors and organizers where a contact--->volunteer--->organizer/director or contact---->organizer/director

sample data:

| eid | peid | role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 7890 | contact |
| 7890 | 1234 | volunteer |
| 7891 | 1234 | volunteer |
| 1234 |  | director |

I tried running a recursive CTE in postgresql but could only figure out the count when using the ID of specific director

```
WITH RECURSIVE ctename AS (
  SELECT eid, role
  FROM reports r
  WHERE eid = '1234'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT r.eid, r.role
  FROM reports r
     JOIN ctename ON r.peid = ctename.eid
)
SELECT role, COUNT(eid) FROM ctename
GROUP BY role
```

OUTCOME (for eid 1234):

| role | reports |
| --- | --- |
| contact | 1521 |
| volunteer | 4 |
| director | 1 |

The desired outcome would give me the all the directors and organizers and all their direct and indirect reports in one table

DESIRED OUTCOME:

| eid | role | reports |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | director | 1526 |
| 1235 | director | 2000 |
| 1236 | director | 50 |
| 1237 | organizer | 3000 |

Comment: please provide sample data or even better prepare a fiddle

Comment: thanks @eshirvana, just added some sample data

Comment: hey @eshirvana! Let me know if the above data sample is ok. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT eid dId, role , eid 
  FROM reports r
  WHERE peid is null
  UNION ALL
  SELECT cte.dId , cte.role , r.eid 
  FROM reports r
  JOIN cte ON r.peid = cte.eid
)
SELECT dId, role, COUNT(*) 
FROM ctename
GROUP BY dId ,role
```

I assumed if the peid is null then they are organizer/director.